# Convert javascript array to object of same keys/values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sweetalert

I have a function that returns an array, as follows:

[image]

But I'm trying to populate a SweetAlert2 dialog.

[As the documentation exemplifies](https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/), the desired input would look like this

```
inputOptions: {
    'SRB': 'Serbia',
    'UKR': 'Ukraine',
    'HRV': 'Croatia'
  },
```

How could I convert my array to the needed format, considering that the key will be the same as the value?

So, something like this would be the result:

```
{
    'aaa123': 'aaa123',
    'Açucena': 'Açucena',
    'Braúnas': 'Braúnas',
    [...]
}
```

I have tried `JSON.stringify`, but the output is not what I need:

> "[["aaa123","Açucena","Braúnas","C.
>   Fabriciano","gege","gegeq2","Ipatinga","Joanésia","Mesquita","Rodoviário","teste","teste2","Timóteo","Tomatoentro","ts"]]"

Comment: ```["aaa123", "Açucena", "Braúnas"].reduce(
  (obj, val) => ({ ...obj, [val]: val }),
  {}
);```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This can be done with a simple `reduce` call:

```js
// Demo data
var source = ['someValue1', 'someValue2', 'someValue3', 'other4', 'other5'];


// This is the "conversion" part
var obj = source.reduce(function(o, val) { o[val] = val; return o; }, {});


// Demo output
document.write(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Comment: Whoa, worked just fine! Can you explain what is it doing, please? Sounds too hacky

Comment: @PhiterFernandes - nothing hacky here, just a simple `reduce` that aggregates the array values into a single object.

Comment: Damn I didn't even know what reduce was back then. That's why it sounded "hacky" for me.

Comment: Two ESlint rules forbid this: no-param-reassign no-return-assign

Answer (score 4):

```
Object.assign(
  {},
  ...['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4', 'value5'].map((value) => ({
    [value]: value,
  })),
)
```

returns

```
{value1: "value1", value2: "value2", value3: "value3", value4: "value4", value5: "value5"}
```

No common ESlint rules error.

Answer (score 3):

if you are using jQuery;

```
$.extend({}, ['x', 'y', 'z']);
```

if you not;

```
Object.assign({}, my_array);
```

Another example;

```js
var arr = [{
  name: 'a',
  value: 'b',
  other: 'c'
}, {
  name: 'd',
  value: 'e',
  other: 'f'
}];

const obj = arr.reduce((total, current) => {
  total[current.name] = current.value;
  return total;
}, {});

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: this does not answer OP's question, it produces an object with numbered keys, instead of the keys being equal to the value

Answer (score 2):

The key to this is that you can assign properties using the obj["string"] technique:

```
function ArrayToObject(arr){
    var obj = {};
    for (var i = 0;i < arr.length;i++){
        obj[arr[i]] = arr[i];
    }
    return obj
}
```